# Getting the error 'Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.'

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2019

I have created a UWP application in VS 2017 And build the application successfully.

When I tried to open the same application in VS2019  and tried to build the application getting the below error:

Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.'

Comment: Based on the error message, it seems the issue is that the project is missing System.Runtime.dll. You could try to perform a NuGet Restore. First check if the "Allow NuGet to download missing packages" is enabled in Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manger -> General. If not, please enable it and build the project again to see if the same issue occurs. Here is a similar [thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/50614/type-universe-cannot-resolve-assembly-systemruntim.html), the solution to that issue is enable the  "Allow NuGet to download missing packages" option.

Comment: Please check the version of the SDK you are building against. Build against the latest version of the SDK. So set the Min and Target versions to 1909 and do a rebuild all. After that, will the same issue occur?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error while attempting to build the project using MSBuild. Initially, manually rebuilding the project from Visual Studio 2019 resolved the issue, and MSBuild via the command line started working as expected. However, replicating the same solution on our TeamCity agent proved challenging.

After further investigation, I found a more reliable solution. The key was to replace the parameters "/t:restore,build" with "/restore" in the MSBuild command. This is how the modified command looked:

```
MSBuild.exe /restore /p:RestorePackagesConfig=true MyProject.csproj [+other parameters]
```

Surprisingly, this change resolved the issue seamlessly. If you encounter a similar problem, consider using the "/restore" parameter as it worked like a charm in my case.